# Steps for solving amortizing payment formula using handheld calculator

Tags: calculator

What are the steps for solving this equation on a handheld calculator?  Where should I start?  I know many calculators have functions to do this quickly, but this is more a question about using a calculator.

$$1199.10 = 200000\left(1+\frac{0.06}{12}\right)^{360} \frac{0.06 / 12}{\left(1+\frac{0.06}{12}\right)^{360}-1}$$

Comment: Are you asking how to enter the right-hand side into a calculator to obtain the left-hand side? What kind of calculator are you using? Also please tell me if I have correctly formatted the equation, as it was extremely ambiguous in its original form.

Comment: Yes, you got it right.  I don't have a particular calculator in mind.  If it matters, I often use the one that comes with Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering this

> question about using a calculator.

With a complicated expression like yours I would compute some of the intermediate ingredients separately and write them down (or save them in the calculator's memory if it has one). Then combine the ingredients.

So
$$
A = \frac{0.06}{12},
$$
$$
B = \left(1+A\right)^{360},
$$
$$
C = 1/(B-1),
$$
$$
1199.10 = 200000 \times B \times A \times C
$$

Along the way you can think about the intermediate values and make sure they seem reasonable. If you do the calculation all at once it will be harder to detect simple typing errors.

Comment: Yup, the alternative is lots and lots of parentheses:
$$200000 \times (1 + 0.06 / 12) ^ {360}\times (0.06/12)  \div ((1+0.06/12)^{360} -1).$$
This will work assuming the calculator obeys order of operations. But I think writing down the intermediate values is more fool-proof, especially for a calculator that doesn't let you see the previous expression you typed in.